# DbContext stored procedures oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameters, dbcontext

I am attempting to execute a stored procedure that has several in/out parameters. This is what the expected way of doing this with SQLServer would be.

```
using (Context)
        {
            const string xml = "<test><testc>testing</testc></test>";
            var userIdParam = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "I_USER_ID", Value = user.ID };
            var dtsParam = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "I_DTS", Value = DateTime.Now };
            var timeoutParam = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "I_TIMEOUT", Value = DateTime.Now };
            var xmlParam = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "I_XML", Value = xml };
            var sessionIdParam = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "O_SESSION_ID", Value = "", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

            var result =
                Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
                    "DALLEN.SP_INSERT_SESSION I_USER_ID, I_DTS, I_TIMEOUT, I_XML, O_SESSION_ID out", 
                    userIdParam,
                    dtsParam, 
                    timeoutParam, 
                    xmlParam, 
                    sessionIdParam);
        }
```

Unfortunately this does not work with oracle. I understand that ref cursors might be used in place of out parameters but that is not my own issue. Is there a good way of passing parameters to the stored procedure using dbcontext.database.sqlquery?

**EDIT**

Error message received when the query attempts to execute. It explains that it doesn't accept sqlParamters so I changed them to OracleParamters and that didn't work either.

*"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'."*

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DALLEN.SP_INSERT_SESSION (
  I_USER_ID                   IN       NUMBER,
  I_DTS                       IN       DATE,
  I_TIMEOUT                   IN       DATE,
  I_XML                       IN       VARCHAR2,
  O_SESSION_ID                OUT      NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT S_SESSION.NEXTVAL
    INTO O_SESSION_ID
    FROM DUAL;

  INSERT INTO DALLEN.SYS_SESSION
              (ID, USER_ID, DTS, TIMEOUT, XML)
       VALUES (O_SESSION_ID, I_USER_ID, I_DTS, I_TIMEOUT, I_XML);
END;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post the full text of the exception you are receiving as well as the procedure? you may use output params in oracle, output cursors require a bit more work than SQL Server

Comment: @Harrison Thanks for the response. I added the two things that you asked for. I have an existing persistence project that uses out params to gather values using that stored procedure so I am pretty sure the stored procedure is fine. What I meant by needing to use ref cursors is that when you import a SP in the EDMX you can only access out parameters that are ref cursors. I could be wrong but that was my understanding based on doing that a couple months ago